# Weird borrowing check failure

Tags: pointers, rust

I have roughly the following code:

```
let val = util::replace(&mut self.some_field[i], self.some_method());
```

It fails with the following message:

```
unrelated.rs:61:65: 61:70 error: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
unrelated.rs:61             let val = util::replace(&mut self.some_field[i], self.some_method());
                                                                             ^~~~~
unrelated.rs:61:36: 61:62 note: second borrow of `*self` occurs here
unrelated.rs:61             let val = util::replace(&mut self.some_field[i], self.some_method());
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can fix this by the following code:

```
let temp = self.some_method();
let val = util::replace(&mut self.some_field[i], temp);
```

But why does it fail? The scopes in which mutable and immutable pointers are taken are distinct, they are different expressions. It looks like kind of bug to me, but I just want to make sure that I'm not missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* a bug: [#6268](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6268).

It is because the borrow checker doesn't account for nested method calls properly yet: the nested calls should be equivalent to the code with the temporary (and thus, should be valid).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I thought. I should have searched for it on the bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

By introducing `temp` you've changed computation order: you first computed `some_method()`, then released `self`, and then got a mutable reference to `some_field` of `self`.

Rust does not allow holding mutable reference along with any other reference (mutable or immutable). See simpler example:

```
struct Foo {
    a: int
}

impl Foo {
    fn ff(&self) -> int { 1 }
}

fn fff(a: int, foo: &mut int) { }
fn ggg(foo: &mut int, a: int) { }

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { a: 0 };
    fff(foo.ff(), &mut foo.a); // this call is valid
    ggg(&mut foo.a, foo.ff()); // this is not
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that mutable reference cannot be used with other references at the same time. But (as I see it) usage of references as method parameters is not really a usage of these reference at the same time. Why mutable pointer in your `ggg` call cannot be released after this argument is computed and before the next argument starts being computing? Expressions which result in parameter values are completely independent, there shouldn't really be any kind of scope, while apparently there is something like scope now.

Comment: Main function body doesn't know that foo.ff() doesn't access foo.a, thus call to foo.ff() is prohibited until release of &mut foo.a, which is after ggg.

Comment: That is my point, why `&mut foo.a` is released only after `ggg` call? It is independent expression, it shouldn't be able to introduce the kind of scope inside the parentheses.

Comment: It is not independent, because pointer to a member of foo (not the value) is passed to `ggg`. So data of `foo` is used inside of `ggg`, till the end of `ggg`.